# print the value properly 1 to 10

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, operators, equality

when i execute this problem, output is blank, why, please explain properly

```
#include<stdio.h>

int  main(){
    int a=0,b;

    for(b=++a;b == 10; b++/*2*/){
        printf("%d",b);//1
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I want to print 1-10 in this method

Comment: This doesn't look like JavaScript.

Comment: Your loop says *while `b` __equals__ `10`*…

Comment: What's the value of `b` on the first iteration through the loop, and does it meet the loop condition?

Comment: I suggest you to read the [tutorial](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It contains invaluable advice on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger**? This will help you step through your code and see what it's actually doing, which can often diverge wildly from what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 2):

Since `b == 10` is `0` on the first iteration, the loop does not run.

Did you mean `b <= 10`?

(For the avoidance of doubt, `b = ++a` sets `b` and `a` to `1`.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you loop will run till `a` will be equal to `10`. In the start `a` will be 1. So the loop doesn't start at all. You need to change `==` with `!=`

```
#include<stdio.h>

int  main(){
    int a=0,b;

    for(b=++a;b != 10; b++/*2*/){
        printf("%d",b);//1
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to print 1-10 in this method

To print numbers from `1` to `10` inclusively using a for loop and the number `10` in the condition of the loop with an equality operator (`==` or `!=`) you can write the loop the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int  main( void )
{
    int a = 0, b;

    for ( b = a; b++ != 10; )
    {
        printf( "%d", b );
    }
}
```

If you need that after the loop the variable `a` had the value `1` then you can write

```
#include <stdio.h>

int  main( void )
{
    int a = 0, b;

    for ( b = a++; b++ != 10; )
    {
        printf( "%d", b );
    }
}
```

Otherwise if after the loop the variables `a` and `b` had values `1` and `10` you can write

```
#include <stdio.h>

int  main( void )
{
    int a = 0, b;

    for ( b = a++; b != 10; )
    {
        printf( "%d", ++b );
    }
}
```

As for your loop then initially `b` is set to 1.

```
b=++a;
```

So it never can be equal to 10 after its initialization.

```
b == 10
```

That is the loop will not be executed.

Comment: It's really unclear why `a` and `b` are present here when `a` isn't really used as anything more than a footstool.

Comment: @tadman I agree. But it seems he needs to write a loop using increment operators and two variables.:)

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code

`for(b = ++a; b == 10; b++/*2*/)`

In first iteration loop breaks because -

1) Initially a becomes 1 before its assignment to b. (i.e b = 1)

2) In first iteration -

```
 b = 1 as (++a equal to 1) 

 b doesn't satisfy (b == 10) condition so it ends the loop.
```

Here is working code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int  main() {
    int a = 0, b;
    for(b = ++a; b <= 10; b++){
        printf("%d\n",b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```